# How to traverse folder tree/subtrees in a windows batch file?

Tags: windows, batch-file

In a windows batch file, is there a way to traverse a folder/subfolders hierarchy doing some action on each file?

Answer (score 15):

Yes, you can do this using the `for` command with the `/r` switch, e.g.:

```
for /r %%f in (*) do echo %%f
```

See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/717171/recursive-renaming-file-names-folder-names-with-a-batch-file) for an example.

Comment: This will traverse every file and directory. Question was only for directories. Use /d to get only directories of 1st level. Use  like /r /d to do it recursively.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `FOR` command with the `/r` switch, which will walk the directory tree executing whatever you specify in the `DO` statement on each directory.  There you can nest another `FOR` statement, using a `dir /b *.*` in the `SET` block.

Answer (score 1):

Fortunately I have quite similar purpose regarding this thread. I believe INSTRUCTION

```
dir /b /s /ad *.* [enter]
```

will produce DIRECTORY TREE as result

```
complete_path\dir_01_lev_01
complete_path\dir_02_lev_01
complete_path\dir_03_lev_01
complete_path\dir_01_lev_01\dir_11_lev_02
complete_path\dir_01_lev_01\dir_12_lev_02
complete_path\dir_02_lev_01\dir_13_lev_02
complete_path\dir_02_lev_01\dir_14_lev_02
complete_path\dir_02_lev_01\dir_15_lev_02
complete_path\dir_03_lev_01\dir_16_lev_02
```

But I want result as below

```
complete_path\dir_01_lev_01
complete_path\dir_01_lev_01\dir_11_lev_02
complete_path\dir_01_lev_01\dir_12_lev_02
complete_path\dir_02_lev_01
complete_path\dir_02_lev_01\dir_13_lev_02
complete_path\dir_02_lev_01\dir_14_lev_02
complete_path\dir_02_lev_01\dir_15_lev_02
complete_path\dir_03_lev_01
complete_path\dir_03_lev_01\dir_16_lev_02
```

So, this SCRIPT is BORN :)

```
@echo off
rem
rem ::: My name is Tree-Folder-8-Level.cmd
rem
setlocal
rem ::: Put started PATH here
set i01=complete_path
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir "%i01%" /ad /on /b') do call :p001 "%%a"
endlocal
goto :eof

:p001
rem ::: Display 1st LEVEL of started PATH
echo %~1
for /f "delims=" %%b in ('dir "%i01%\%~1" /ad /on /b') do call :p002 "%~1\%%b"
goto :eof

:p002
rem ::: Display 2nd LEVEL of started PATH
echo %~1
for /f "delims=" %%c in ('dir "%i01%\%~1" /ad /on /b') do call :p003 "%~1\%%c"
goto :eof

:p003
rem ::: Display 3rd LEVEL of started PATH
echo %~1
for /f "delims=" %%d in ('dir "%i01%\%~1" /ad /on /b') do call :p004 "%~1\%%d"
goto :eof

:p004
rem ::: Display 4th LEVEL of started PATH
echo %~1
for /f "delims=" %%e in ('dir "%i01%\%~1" /ad /on /b') do call :p005 "%~1\%%e"
goto :eof

:p005
rem ::: Display 5th LEVEL of started PATH
echo %~1
for /f "delims=" %%f in ('dir "%i01%\%~1" /ad /on /b') do call :p006 "%~1\%%f"
goto :eof

:p006
rem ::: Display 6th LEVEL of started PATH
echo %~1
for /f "delims=" %%g in ('dir "%i01%\%~1" /ad /on /b') do call :p007 "%~1\%%g"
goto :eof

:p007
rem ::: Display 7th LEVEL of started PATH
rem :::     and 8th LEVEL of started PATH
echo %~1
for /f "delims=" %%h in ('dir "%i01%\%~1" /ad /on /b') do echo %~1\%%h
goto :eof
```

Brighter ideas are welcome. :)

Answer (score 0):

if you want to query folders in some location and traverse them, then you should first write the result of the query to a text file and then traverse lines of file content.
Following example shows how to find first level subfolders whose name contain 'dev'
and traverse them:

```
if exist FolderList.txt (
 del FolderList.txt
)
set query=dev
set /a count=0
pushd %yourLocation%
dir /ad /o-d /b *%query%* >> FolderList.txt
for /f "tokens=*" %%a in ('type FolderList.txt') do (
 set /a count+=1
 echo %count%."%%a"

)
popd 

Some sample results could be:
1.Adev
2.bDevc
3.devaa
```

Answer (score -1):

```
dir /b /s /ad *.* | sort
```

That should give the same results regardless of the path depth