# 7-Zip Command-Line Help (Batch File)

Tags: shell, batch-file, command-line, command-line-arguments, 7zip

I need to run 7-Zip from a batch file and perform a few tasks, I was wondering if it was possible.  Here is my situation:

I have a folder "X:/Archived Backups/" that contains archives and sub-directories with archives.

Some of these archives also contain further archives.

I need to recursively scan the directory and sub-directories and 7-Zip to extract each archive to a folder by the same name (archive name).

I also need it to extract archives within archives within archives etc.

Finally, I need it to delete the archives when extracted (this includes the archives within archives) and only leave the extracted folders.

Is this possible?  If so is it possible from the command line?  How would I do it?

Many Thanks
:)

Comment: The answer depends heavily on the shell you are using. Which one is it?

Comment: @jlahd  with x: as a drive letter then it has to be Windows.

Comment: @foxidrive Windows is an operating system, not a shell. I was kind of hoping that the asker was not limited to `cmd.exe`, which unfortunately is Windows's default shell.

Comment: Yes Windows.  I got it sorted.  Thanks for your replies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Test this to see if it does what you need - it should extract them to `x:\extracted\path\filename` folders.

It doesn't delete the archives because you have to test this first.

Check the path to `7z.exe` first.

```
@echo off
set "location=x:\extracted"
md "%location%" 2>nul
for /r "X:\Archived Backups" %%a in (*.7z) do (
   md "%location%\%%~pna"
      pushd "%location%\%%~pna" && ("c:\program files\7-zip\7z.exe" x "%%a" & popd)
)
pause
```

Comment: As for the deletion part, i used `del /S /F *.zip *.7z *.rar` etc. to remove the archives.  I then removed all empty directories with `for /f "usebackq delims=" %%d in (`"dir /ad/b/s | sort /R"`) do rd "%%d"`

Comment: Did you also use `*.zip *.7z *.rar` in my script?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1307935/how-to-traverse-folder-tree-subtrees-in-a-windows-batch-file) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/138981/how-do-i-test-if-a-file-is-a-directory-in-a-batch-script)  as  starting points.

For iteration and testing directory:

```
FOR %%i IN (%VAR%) DO IF EXIST %%~si\NUL ECHO It's a directory
```

For files, check file extension and extract using 7-zip command :

Comment: Thank you for your reply.  I got it sorted :)