# renaming files in subdirectories with a DOS-Batch

Tags: windows, batch-file, rename

i want a BATch to check if 2 given files are in the directory
+ if they are change their names

so far i have gotten this:

```
@echo off

if exist %order.xml && %order.xml.orig goto RENAME
goto END

:RENAME
rename order.xml order.xml.old
rename order.xml.orig order.xml

:END
pause
```

which works just fine, but the problem is i have to copy this into each subdirectory.
is there a way to let the BATch check every subfolder? everything i tryed just gave me an syntax-error

Comment: you can use for /r to walk subdirectories and execute commands on them

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for this:

[recursive renaming file names + folder names with a batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/717171/recursive-renaming-file-names-folder-names-with-a-batch-file)

All it is is a for loop with a goto statement. The answer actually just renames files, not folders so should be exactly what you wanted.