# Batch script to copy/delete folders matching a certain name and preserving their directory tree

Tags: batch-file, copy, xcopy, robocopy

I am wondering whether it is possible to write a batch script for `CMD.EXE` (Target system: MS Windows 2k3) for doing the following:

Let us have folder `rootfolder` containing a lot of files and directories. Some of the subdirectories (at different levels) might be called `dirname`. I would like to create a folder `rootfolder2`, copying the directory tree structure of `rootfolder` but containing only  the folders `dirname` with their content. I would also like to delete the same folders after having them copied in `rootfolder2`

Example:

```
rootfolder
 `- dir1
 `- dir2
     `- filew
     `- dirname
         `- filey
 `- dirname
     `- file1
     `- dirx
         `- file2
 `- filez
```

And the output I'm looking for would be:

```
rootfolder
 `- dir1
 `- dir2
     `- filew
 `- filez

rootfolder2
 `- dir2
     `- dirname
         `- filey
 `- dirname
     `- file1
     `- dirx
         `- file2
```

Can I do this without having to write a console application in C/C++/Java/etc.

Thanks in advance,
Joe

---

Here's the answer to my question using simply xcopy and batch scripting:

```
@echo off
setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
set StartDir=Folder1
set BackupDir=Folder1 BK
mkdir "%BackupDir%"
call :ProcessDir "%StartDir%"
exit /b 0
:ProcessDir
    echo Processing directory "%~1"
    for /f "delims=" %%d in ('dir /ad /b "%~1"2^>nul') do (
        if "%%d"=="foldername" ( 
            xcopy /s /e /i "%~1\%%d" "%BackupDir%\%~1\%%d" 
            rmdir /S /Q "%~1\%%d"   
        ) else ( 
            call :ProcessDir "%~1\%%~d"
        )
    )
    exit /b 0
```

credits go to: [recursive renaming file names + folder names with a batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/717171/recursive-renaming-file-names-folder-names-with-a-batch-file)

Comment: Have you tried using robocopy?

Comment: Thanks, I did but with no luck. Modified by message!

Comment: Surely thats exactly what the move function of robocopy does though? I must have missed why its not worked.

Comment: BugFinder, would you mind sharing the flags to achieve it?

Comment: robocopy source dest filespec [more filespecs] /move /s .. so something like robocopy rootfolder rootfolder2 dirname/*.* file1 file2 /move /s

Comment: I'm not sure I understand how the above will work with the above situation - it also gives me an error on the "dirname/*.*" parameter. By the way, I do not know which will be the content of my "dirname" in advance. Thanks, Regards.

Comment: But you said you knew the directory name. Hence I added it..

Comment: directory name yes but still the error is present when launching the command. It is the directory content that is not known in advance.

Comment: You can add your "answer" as a regular answer and recognize it as such, if you want to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Here's the answer to my question using simply xcopy and batch
>   scripting:

```vb
@echo off
setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
set StartDir=Folder1
set BackupDir=Folder1 BK
mkdir "%BackupDir%"
call :ProcessDir "%StartDir%"
exit /b 0
:ProcessDir
    echo Processing directory "%~1"
    for /f "delims=" %%d in ('dir /ad /b "%~1"2^>nul') do (
        if "%%d"=="foldername" ( 
            xcopy /s /e /i "%~1\%%d" "%BackupDir%\%~1\%%d" 
            rmdir /S /Q "%~1\%%d"   
        ) else ( 
            call :ProcessDir "%~1\%%~d"
        )
    )
    exit /b 0
```

> credits go to:
>   [recursive renaming file names + folder names with a batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/717171/recursive-renaming-file-names-folder-names-with-a-batch-file)

*That way it's done!*