# Batch file to rename files in multiple folders

Tags: batch-file, directory, rename

I have the folder and file structure as given below. I am in need of a MS DOS batch file to rename the files in multiple folders. Can anyone please help out?

```
- Main Folder

    -->Sub Folder1
        --- File1_EN.txt
        --- File2_EN.txt

    --> Sub Folder2
        --- File3_EN.txt
        --- File4_EN.txt
```

I want to rename  the suffix "EN" in file names to "ENU".

Comment: Have you looked at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/717171/recursive-renaming-file-names-folder-names-with-a-batch-file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@echo off
for /D %%d in (*) do (
   ren "%%d\File*_EN.txt" "File*_ENU.txt"
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by this way:

```
@Echo OFF

Set "Folder=C:\Users\Administrador\Desktop\Nueva carpeta"
Set "Suffix=_EN"
Set "Replace=_ENU"
Set "RegEx=\".*%Suffix%\"$" 

FOR /R "%Folder%" %%# in ("*") DO (
    (Echo "%%~n#"| FINDSTR /I "%RegEx%" 1>NUL) && (
    Set "NewFileName=%%~nx#"
    Call Set "NewFileName=%%NewFileName:%Suffix%=%Replace%%%"
    Call Echo [+] Renaming: "%%~nx#" "%%NewFileName%%"
    Ren "%%#" "%%NewFileName%%"
    )
)

Pause&Exit
```

The Findstr is to ensure the matched string is a suffix, is better than doing a substring or splitting the filename from "_" character to the right.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
ren folder1\file*.txt file*_enu.txt
ren folder2\file*.txt file*_enu.txt
```

Comment: Your method works only if the new name is larger than the original. If the new name is shorter, it fails...

Comment: I always post solutions for a specific question of an OP. Batch as a scripting language can never answer to all thinkable issues of a case.[How did wildcards work in MS-DOS?](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2007/12/17/6785519.aspx) AND this also works: `ren file*.txt file*e.txt`, new filenames are `file?_e.txt`.

Comment: Yes, I used to do the same :) My comment is not a criticism of your answer, but an explanatory note if someone think they may use the same method for a new shorter name...

Answer (score 0):

If you want all child folders to be changed use:

```
for /f "delims=*" %a in ('dir File*_EN.txt /b /s') do ren "%a" File*_ENU.txt
```