# Renaming files with wildcards/regular expressions

Tags: vba

I have a text file called `SampleTestFile.ghi`. After this file is processed by a program, it is renamed and moved into another folder. The naming convention used when renaming the file is `*.abc`

So I have the file name (`SampleTestfile.ghi`), I have the naming convention (`*.abc`), but how can I convert the original file name into the processed filename using VBA? Is there a way I can say

```
ProcessFileName = "SampleTestFile.ghi" & "*.abc" 
''and get the correct answer of SampleTestFile.abc ?
```

Comment: Okay which program is processing the file? How do you know that the file was processed? Based on your file extension it doesnt look like a Microsoft Office file. I think a better option for you, would be to move all the processed files into one folder, and a run a batch script file to rename all processed files in the folder. Check this, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16162103/batch-file-to-rename-files-in-multiple-folders

Comment: is the `.abc` a FILE EXTENSION or part of the FILE NAME?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ProcessFileName = Replace(sampleTestFileName, ".ghi",".abc")
```

Assuming ".ghi" never occurs in the middle of the filename

Probably safer to use `Mid()`

```
Sub Test()

    Dim s
    s = "my strange filename.ghi here.ghi"

    Debug.Print "original", s

    'Method 1 (has a potential problem)
    Debug.Print "method 1", Replace(s, ".ghi", ".abc")

    'Method 2 (safer)
    Mid(s, Len(s) - 3, 4) = ".abc"
    Debug.Print "method 2", s

End Sub
```

Comment: That gives me an idea. I can just replace the * wildcard in the processed file naming convention with the original file name. Thanks!